# Call to a member function first() on null

Tags: laravel

When I try to fetch my `user` data, I receive the error

> Call to a member function first() on null

```
public function show($id) {
    $user=User::findOrFail($id);
    $employee = $user->employees->first();
         
    return view('admin.profile')
            ->with(['employee' => $employee , 'user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: does your $user have any data ??

Comment: Try `$user->employees()->first();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in your `User` model.

Check that you have declared the `employees` relationship:

```php
public function employees()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Employee::class); // I'm assuming you have a Employee model with expected column names, but feel free to replace everything with what you actually have in your app
}
```

If the problem persists, edit your question with your tables structure and your models.

Answer (score 0):

It's very useful to understand the difference between `$user->employees` and `$user->employees()`.

- `$user->employees`: returns a `Collection` of employee models, or `null` if none are found.
- `$user->employees()`: returns a query builder instance that you can chain additional conditions to (`where`'s, etc).

Both options have a `first()` option available to them, but one is using a `Collection` method, where the other is using the query builder method.

Some have already suggested this, and I will as well - the safer and simplest solution to your problem is to use the query builder version of the relationship, since there is no risk of the `employees()` result being `null`. It also has the added benefit of not needing to load the entire relationship into a collection just to get the first result.

In short: `$user->employees()->first();` is the best way to go.